# Store/Sync Events in Google Calendar in Ruby Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

In my Rails Application i am having a module called appointments. I want to alerts those appointment events for each and every user via Google Calendar. So I want to Store/Sync Events in Google  Calendar in Ruby Application. I want to allow to store appointments in their own account not all in a single gmail account. For eg: UserA appointments will be synced into UserA's gmail/GoogleCalendar account and UserB's appointments will be synced into UserB's gmail/GoogleCalendar account.

Is there any gems or possibilties to do this and Rails version of application is 2.3.10 and Ruby  1.8.7. Can you please suggest me any gems.

Thank You

Comment: Are you in need of a rubygem already made and don't want to implement your own using the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview)? It has a Ruby quickstart and with a few API calls can do what you're intended to implement.

Comment: Yes I need a Ruby Gem... As my application Ruby version is  1.8.7... Calendar API needs Ruby >= 2.0